# Using Remainders to Round Up

Tags: java, modulus

I'm very much struggling with an online Java course, having minimal experience in C++...

Here's the problem:

The Fast Freight Shipping Co charges $1.10 per 500 miles for a 2-lb package. The shipping charges are not prorated, i.e. a 2-lb package shipped 550 miles would cost $2.20.

my basic code is:

```
if (weight <= 2)
   price = 1.1 * (distance / 500);
```

However, I can't figure out how to use the remainder of 50 lbs to double the shipping charges. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mathematical function called ceiling, to do this. It will take a value and round it up (unless it is aleady an integer).

You will need to first divide the distance by 500, take the ceiling, and multiply it by the shipping rate:

```
// I'm assuming distance is an int
double price = 1.10 * Math.ceil(distance/500.0);
```

Note that if `distance` is an int, the `500.0` cannot be written as `500`, since then there would be implicit rounding downward (since it's an integer divided by an integer).

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly... no wonder i couldn't figure it out. can't find anything about that function in the chapter we're studying!

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with currency in java, use BigDecimal.